# How to filter an input from file? (PHP)

Tags: php, function, input, filter

First of all I am new to PHP world.. so it would be much appreciated if i found what i needed here. many thanks in advance.

I have an input file with multiple lines, each line has some persons names and where they are living ( names and locations separated by tap (it may not show perfectly below) ) . just like this example:

- JhonWilliam        NewYork
- KhanFayre          Bangalore
- LuiseRamsy         NewYork

so i wanted to write a PHP function to read that file line by line and **only** print(output to another file) people who live in NewYork

i wrote this function to read the file line by line

```
function process_file($input)

{

  $handle = @fopen("input.txt", "r");

  if ($handle) {

     while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

         echo process_line(trim($buffer));

     }

     fclose($handle);

  }

}


process_file("input.txt");


?>
```

my question is .. **How can i write a function to filter the text in the input file? because i only want to print the people who live in NewYork**

Comment: Why don't you just add another parameter to your function `function process_file($input,$location = 'new york')`

Comment: have you considered keeping the data in "input.txt" in a database instead of a flat file? this would make what you are describing extremely simple.

Comment: fgetcsv() is a useful function function for reading tab-separated files

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find out whether if an string contains another string.

```
function process_line($str, $findme) {
    if (strpos($str, $findme) !== false) {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

And

```
echo process_line(trim($buffer), 'NewYork');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      $handle = @fopen("input.txt", "r");

      if ($handle) {

         while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

           $n = explode('\t',$buffer)   // $n[0] = name, $n[1] = city
           if ( $n[1] == "NewYork" ) {
             echo $n[0] . "\n";
           }
         }

         fclose($handle);

      }
```